# RIP Rutger Hauer, actor for Roy Batty

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Variety reports](https://variety.com/2019/film/news/rutger-hauer-dead-dies-blade-runner-co-star-1203278050/) that Rutger Hauer, actor in *Sin City*, *Batman Begins*, *True Blood*, and other sci-fi and horror films, has died at 75.

He will perhaps be best remembered for his role in *Blade Runner* as Roy Batty, a Replicant hunted by Rick Deckard (Harrison Ford). During his final moments, he gives a monologue about what he has seen, which seems like a fitting sendoff for the actor's life.

Comment: Somewhat against his usual type, he also played a straight fantasy hero character in *Ladyhawke*.

Comment: Sigh. He played in tons of SFF movies and eveyone just remembers one role :(

Comment: Let's not forget that Rutger Hauer was a classically trained actor. He played in plays by Shakespeare and Steinbeck. He debuted on Dutch television in _Floris_, a series directed by Paul Verhoeven, with whom he would go on to make a number of films.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - In fairness, many of those roles were truly dreadful. He seemed to be drawn to a paycheque like a moth to a flame

Comment: "and other sci-fi films..." Wedlock! https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103239/

Comment: What is the etiquette for votes on a post like this? I'm upvoting because I was always a fan.

Comment: Unfortunately, in his home country Holland, many took issue with him as a Hollywood sell-out. I loved him in Ladyhawke.

Comment: @DaveInCaz - Meta votes mean "I approve" or "I agree"

Comment: Far removed from anything remotely Sci-Fi or Fantasy related, but Hauer was outstanding in a British made-for-tv movie called "Escape from Sobibor", about the real life prisoner revolt and escape from the Nazi death camp of the same name.  Great actor. RIP

Comment: And he had too small a role in _Valérian_. They should have cast him as the evil commander.

Comment: He was also terrifying in the Hitcher. A great actor who made B movies better. ... _If only you could see what I've seen with your eyes..._

Comment: @Valorum: “He seemed to be drawn to a paycheque like a moth to a flame” — yeah it's so weird when people want to get paid for working.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - There are a few 'jobbing' actors who'll work on anything. Michael Ironside, Michael Caine and Gerard Depardieu are examples of those that seem to value quantity of work over quality. Daniel Day Lewis is the opposite.